# Execution time in mongo with different amount of returned results is the same

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I query mongodb with pymongo to get results within date range timestamp.

My query looks like this:

```
start_TW = time.time()

startforTF = datetime(2016, 6, 1, 5, 0, 0).isoformat()
endforTF = datetime(2016, 6, 2, 5, 0, 0).isoformat()

pipeline=  [{"$match": {"properties.timestamp": {"$gte": startforTF, "$lte": endforTF}}},
            { "$project" : {"properties.vessel_hash":"$properties.vessel_hash", "geometry.coordinates":"$geometry.coordinates", "_id":0}}]

fetchPosOfShipInTimewindow = db.samplecol.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True) 

end_TW = time.time()
print "Time to fetch all positions inside time frame: ", (end_TW - start_TW)
```

The query seems to work fine but I observe something odd. The execution time to fetch the results in a range of one day is pretty much the same with the execution time in a range of ten days.

For a range of one day the results are:

--execution time -> 0, 45

--records returned from dataset: 1.142.316

For a range of ten days the results are:

--execution time -> 0, 32

--records returned from dataset: 14.309.233

I do not understand how mongo manage to achieve this. Did mongo cache some results?

Comment: Do you have an index on `properties.timestamp`? Because if you don't it has to read the whole collection in both cases.

Comment: I do not have because I want to see the difference in time if I have an Index and if I have not. But the strange thing is that the execution time is the same in both cases. Do you know what I miss here?

Comment: If you do not have an index there will be no difference because MongoDB has to read the whole collection (maybe 100M records for all we know) in both cases.

Comment: Also: doesn't `aggregate` return a result cursor? Are you actually fetching the data?

Comment: I try with index now. Yes aggregate return a result cursor. Then I fetch the data in python.

Comment: It looks like you record the `end_TW` before fetching the data.

Comment: So you suggest to run the aggregate query , fetch the data and then end_TW. Ok, this makes sense. Thank you @Thilo